# Logical Error - convert Fah to Celsius

Tags: c, formula, date-arithmetic

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define F(x) 32 + (x*9)/5

int main(void)
{ 
  int F,C;
  printf ("Enter temperature in celsius=");
  scanf ("%d",&C);
  F(C);

  printf (" %d fahrenheit = %d celsius\n", F, C);

  return 0;
 }
```

When I input 10 celsius, it comes out some as:

```
1798680630 fahrenheit = 10 celsius
```

Am I writing the formula wrongly? I can't seem to figure out the error. 
Just a beginner, going through my tutorials. Thank you!

Comment: You forgot to add a `F=` in front of `F(C)`, because you want to assign the value to your variable `F`. http://ideone.com/Xc6c3x

Comment: [Why confuse people?](https://blog.codinghorror.com/coding-for-violent-psychopaths/)

Comment: First of all, given that these are ints, you might lose too much information while dividing. Secondly, you shouldn't (can't) have both a variable F and a macro F, it's bound to have errors. See the answers below about why your code doesn't work

Comment: @sourav hilarious! thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You are not storing the result of the macro expansion at all. So, `F` is uninitilized.

IMO, the macro isn't needed at all. Just use a variable:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  int C;
  float F;
  printf ("Enter temperature in celsius=");
  scanf ("%d",&C);
  F = 32 + (C*9)/5.0;
  printf (" %f fahrenheit = %d celsius\n", F, C);

  return 0;
 }
```

Notice that I used the literal `5.0` so that you don't perform just integer division.

Comment: thank you! i changed it to macro as the simpler one didnt give me the right output.  ill try again.

Answer (score 0):

You don't save output of `F()` to a variable. It should be:

```
  (...)
  F = F(C);

  printf (" %d fahrenheit = %d celsius\n", F, C);
```

Currently you are printing an *uninitialized variable* which is undefined behavior and is quite dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the address of the F. Also do not waste variables.

Remove

```
F(C);
```

Do your printing like :

```
printf (" %d fahrenheit = %d celsius\n", F(C), C);
```